# How can I create pages without removing the navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When creating a website with pages, we can switch pages
by using `a href="..."`

An example could be,

```
<li> <a href= "index.html"> Home> </li>
<li> <a href="locations.html> Locations </li>
...
```

However, on every page I have a navigation bar which should be present, so I was thinking of doing something like this,

```
<nav id=navigation_bar">
...
</div>


<div id="page"> </div>
```

Where I can swap the desired page contents to the "page" div and defaulting to `index.html`.
How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Look into SPA frameworks like Angular or React. Also back-end can build your page including all common parts in page from different files

Comment: to implement this you need to make a single page application and for that you should use react or angular.

Comment: @BilalMohammad why Angular or React ? can't it be VUE ? or other ? :)

Comment: @MihaiT Yes you can use vue, it totally depends on what you prefer.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a framework/library - after all they are is JS and similar. Could you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve? For example do you want to minimise network traffic or isn't that a consideration?

Comment: @AHaworth I have unfortunately already structured a large website that I have been working on and currently have multiple pages. However they are all within one container with seperate id's such as "about_container". To achieve pages switching I have a fading effect where I decrease the opacity of the visible page to 0 and increase the opacity of the next desired page to 1. This have caused issues with using position:fixed within each page to ignore stacking. I have later learnt this tactic and I am trying to rewrite it so the page switching is nicer.

Comment: @Justinas hmm, Maybe I should just take the L that I have written my current website poorly and rewrite it. Current structure and page implementation in above comment.

Comment: Are you able to putup a small bit of code with dummy content and say 3 of your 'pages' as I don't understand why, say, setting a page to a lower z-index as you gradually reduce its opacity won't work - obviously something to do with fixed as you say but what?

Comment: @AHaworth oh that is a decent idea, I did not that of decreasing the Z-index.

Comment: Thinking more about it, I don't think it will help as fixed creates its own stacking context.

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of iframe and javascript to accomplish the same

Comment: Here is an Code sandbox link to achieve same - https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-tereshkova-7n7jo?file=/index.html